# Swift Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift

Here is my code:

```
func cache<T: Cacheable>(type: Int, items: Array<T>, options: CacheOptions?) {
    log(log_http, "caching ... \(items)")

    for item: Cacheable in items {
        let key: String? = item.primaryKeyValue()
    }
}
```

It's pretty simple, Cacheable is a protocol:

```
public protocol Cacheable: class {
    func primaryKeyValue() -> String?
}
```

And the compile always fails with signal issue.
However if I remove :class from Cacheable, the compile will go through, but when I need:

```
NSCache().setObject(item, forKey: "key")
```

it complains that Cacheable does not conform to AnyObject protocol, so I stuck here. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Just removing `:Cacheable` from `for item: Cacheable {` solve the problem?

Comment: nope, it becomes 'T' does not conform AnyObject protocol

Comment: Not from `cache<T: Cacheable>`, but from `for item: Cacheable in items {`. Try `for item in items {`.

Comment: Apple's Swift team usually regards swift compiler segfault as a compiler bug. You should report it to Apple.

Comment: @rintaro yes that's what I did.